# iPhone/mobile select input: remove background shading

Tags: css, webkit

I have a select box and I'd like to remove the input's gray shading that appears on the iPhone. I just want it to be white or transparent. I have not tried it on an Android yet.

```
<select id = "my_select">
   <option>Choose me!</option>
</select>
```

I have tried:

```
#my_select{background:white}
```

This does not remove the gray shaded background.

And I've tried:

```
#my_select{-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

This removes the background, but also the drop-down arrow.